# How to calculate gradient manually in backpropagation if the neural network architecture consists of linear, batch norm, leaky relu, linear?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

What are the steps to manually calculate the backpropagation gradient with the architecture that I mentioned? because I'm confused, the architecture on google regarding backprop is different from the neural network architecture that I use, I'm confused about the linear layer that doesn't use the activation function and how to calculate the gradient on the batch norm with its derivative function.

I've tried to calculate the gradient loss to output, here the loss I use is bcewithlogitsloss, then I try to calculate the linear layer by multiplying the output of the previous layer by the gradient loss to output, and starting here I feel wrong. the output I want is a gradient value that I can use to update the weights with the adam optimizer. thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The specific problem I'm asking is, regarding the correct steps in finding gradients and applying the derivative function in the backprop based on the architecture I've mentioned, I'm experiencing confusion in finding gradients in the linear layer because there is no activation function, as well as confusion in calculating the derivative formula on normal batches